# Recognize if removable drive was inserted

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-services

I have a piece of code to check the removable drives connected to the computer. But I have to check when the drive is available or inserted into the USB port.Should I write a while loop constantly checking for the drive with certain ID to become available? If I make it into a windows service, do I have to do the same i.e keep looping until the device is found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a hidden window and use it to listen for [WM_DEVICECHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363480%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) messages.

Whatever you do, don't poll. That's horribly wasteful and inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could use WMI (from C++ this will mean using WMI's COM API): creation events for the [`Win32_LogicalDisk`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173%28VS.85%29.aspx) class.